# netsh command : blocking a port

Tags: netsh

i'm trying to block/allow the 80 port to block/allow internet access in browsers.
i referred to this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709 about netsh commands.

my command was :
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”allow80” protocol=TCP dir=out localport=80 action=block

the cmd asked me for admin rights, after running with admin rights, running the commands returns ok. but i does absolutely nothing, i'm still allowed to browse the web.

what can be wrong?

Comment: How about 8080? Also, you might need to reboot for it to take effect.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but i'm using SetTcpEntry http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366378(v=vs.85).aspx and loop all connections every x seconds, and close the connection if the port is detected.

Answer (score 2):

change localport=80 to remoteport=80

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you set the local port as tcp 80, but you build an outgoing rule, technically the local port is the source port for this kind of rule because you start a connection to the remote port (destination port) tcp 80 to any site on internet, you must change the localport to remoteport parameter.

Regards.